# Как подписать письмо?

Tags: выбор-слова, одним-словом, синонимы

Как подписать письмо, если я пишу родственникам (бабушке и дедушке)? У меня с ними не близкие отношения, поэтому я не уверена, как подписать. Единственное, что приходит в голову, - "Ваша Настя". Или такое не подходит?

У вас есть другие идеи? Спасибо!

Comment: Small edits are not allowed with my level of rep. It should be `Единственное` (double н) and `приходит`, not `приходить`.

Comment: @sharptooth ok, спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы просто подписал  "Настя".

Comment: Ничего, что тебя Саша зовут?

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- он имел в виду, что подписал бы "Настя", если бы был Настей. Разве это не понятно?

Comment: @Anixx, oh, when you say it like that it makes perfect sense: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TYdrfm7yaI

Comment: А мне любопытно: не очень близкие бабушка и дедушка тоже выдуманы?

Comment: Скорее всего, да, мне так кажется. Тут вобще ничего настоящего нету!

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- Судя по нику - автор вопроса тоже не Настя.

Comment: Судить - плохо, не по-христьянски это.

Answer (score 7):

- C уважением
- Вечно ваша
- Искренне ваша
- Ваша покорная слуга
- Навеки ваша раба Настя
- Ваша любимая внученка
- По гроб обязанная
- Так и живу
- Спасибо
- Всего доброго
- Если что, обращайтесь
- Очень жаль, что так получилось
- Благодарю
- Будьте всегда так же молоды и красивы
- С уважением к Вам и к Вашему бизнесу
- С почтением
- Успехов
- Пусть у вас все будет хорошо
- Очень приятно
- Заранее спасибо
- Надеюсь, понятно написала
- Всего наилучшего
- Желаю вам всегдашней радости в судьбе
- Желаю удачи
- Удачи вам в ваши добрых начинаниях
- Сообщите, если будут вопросы
- С пожеланием всего наилучшего
- Счастья вам
- Желаю вам море счастья
- Крепкого кавказского здоровья вам и долголетия
- Всего хорошего
- С любовью
- С искренними извинениями
- Не принимайте близко к сердцу
- Так уж вышло
- Желаю вам, чтобы все были здоровы
- Долгих лет жизни вам
- Скоро увидимся
- Простите за беспокойство
- Не болейте
- Пишите
- Звоните
- Не отчаивайтесь
- Пусть ваши желания пренепременно сбудутся
- Вспоминайте о мне иногда
- Улыбайтесь почаще
- С нетерпением жду ответа
- Жду ответа, как соловей лета
- Желаю вам многих богатств и процветания
- Не держите зла
- До скорой встречи
- Надеюсь, вы рассмотрите мое предложение
- До свидания
- Буду рада помочь
- Надеюсь на совместное плодотворное сотрудничество
- Простите за все
- Простите за все, если можете
- Прощайте
- Целую
- Обнимаю
- Люблю
- Сожалею
- Тоскую по вам
- Чмоки
- Пока
- Пока-пока
- Чао-о-о
- Не забывайте
- Не поминайте лихом
- Пусть у вас все сложится
- Мои искренние соболезнования
- Ну, наверное все
- Не знаю, что еще написать
- В добрый путь
- Ждите в гости
- Приезжайте скорее
- С богом
- Как-то так
- Такие дела
- Ну, теперь точно все
- Вот
- Конец

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8395?hl=ru

Comment: Даже не могу выбрать какой вариант самый смешной в контексте письма не очень близким бабушке и дедушке: "Чмоки" или "Надеюсь на совместное плодотворное сотрудничество"?

Comment: You've forgot чмоки-чмоки (XOXO in English).

Comment: Так уж вышло? :D :D

Comment: And "Покеда, бабанька, поливайте фикус"?

Answer (score 2):

@Ellen, on the Russian your name truly translated as "Лена", not a "Настя".

If you don't know how to finish your letter, simply write:

"Пишите!"

It means write me back. To keep intensity of correspondence.

or

"Люблю! Целую!"

It means action "Kiss you!" and "Love you!"

Actually, "Ваша Настя" sounds very well.